# Passing different data types to uint parameter

Tags: solidity, data-types, function

I found out, that **I can** pass different data types (as argument), even if the Solidity method takes only uint data type, **why** is that possible?

Example:

```
function test (uint _param) public {
   //do smth
}
test(address(ADDRESS_VAR))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no data type in the calldata. They are all coded as hexadecimal. So if you pass to the contract an address like this: `0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D`, EVM thinks, "ok, there is no problem. It is a number". Because you can convert it to uint: `697323163401596485410334513241460920685086001293`.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking this because I found out that I can maliciously modify state variables of a contract using a delegate call, even when it's a different type than what the function wants. This helped a lot, thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome! You are right, this method gives facilities in the delegatecall attacks. Because of that, anyone who uses delegatecall, he has to know what he is doing.